# Limiting Map Reduce Job to use less resource

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn

I am using Hadoop 2.5.0-cdh5.3.3 . I created a map reduce job that results in large number of map jobs. Hence it is consuming all the resources. How can I prevent it to use only limited resource ?

Answer (score 0):

You can either increase the block size 64 mb to a higher config, 
or 
You can set a parameter called "mapred.map.tasks" to limit the number of map tasks per node.

Note: This will affect performance since more number of blocks will be allocated to task tracker node.